# How to manualy construct argv? (or: converting a vector of strings into a `char**`)

Tags: c++, argv, dpdk

I need to use a function (`eal_setup` provided by dpdk) that as arguments accepts `argc` and `argv`, and is supposed to be called first thing in your `main` function, taking the `argc` and `argv` directly from the call of the application.

The app however needs to be able to accept arguments for other reasons, and some arguments for `eal_setup` I will never need to change from a default I set them to. This has made a need to manually construct a "fake" `argv`, by which I mean a `char**` type variable that contains whatever information I want to pass into `eal_setup`.

So, what I end up doing is, after processing the real `argc` and `argv` with `CLI11`, I construct an `std::vector<std::string>`, which I pass through a function supposed to turn the information from a vector of strings into a `char**`, before using it with `eal_setup`.

The function I created doesn't work. It compiles, but whenever I try to access an element of the result the same way I would on `argv`, I get a segmentation error.

```cpp
char** construct_argv(std::vector<std::string> std_argv){
    std::vector<char*> vec_argv;
    for (std::string str_arg : std_argv){
        vec_argv.insert(vec_argv.begin(), (char*)str_arg.c_str());
    }
    return vec_argv.data();
}
```

How do I fix this? How can I convert an `std::vector<std::string>` into a `char**` correctly, to create a mock `argv`?

Comment: Return the whole vector (`vec_argv`), and use `.data()` from it. You should also use (const) ref for `std_argv`/`str_arg`

Comment: Is there any reason for the reversing of the order of the arguments?

Comment: @molbdnilo none, it's an artifact of a previous iteration of the code. I only realised afterwards and have since used `.end()` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char** construct_argv(std::vector<std::string> std_argv){
```

`std_argv` is a parameter to this function. Function parameters are just like local variables. When the function returns all local variables get destroyed. They cease to exist. They become no more. They start pining for the fjords. They become ex-objects.

Your `construct_argv` carefully constructs a vector of pointers to each one, and returns it:

```
return vec_argv.data();
```

But, of course, you earned double the headache as your reward. `vec_argv` is another local object. This returns a pointer to the vector's internal data. And the vector gets destroyed immediately, because this function returns. You're left holding a completely empty bag, full of pointers to destroyed objects, that's itself destroyed.

This entire function must be re-engineered from scratch. There are many different ways to do this correctly. One way is to pass `std_argv` by reference, and let the caller be responsible for not letting the original `std::vector<std::string>` go out of scope and get destroyed. And then return `vec_argv` itself and make the caller responsible for getting its `data()`.

```
(char*)str_arg.c_str()
```

This cast is fugly. Since C++11 `std::string`'s `data()` is guaranteed to be null-terminated, so this can be `str_arg.data()`, too.